# Adjust multirow column length without nesting

Tags: tables, multirow

How can I allow a multirow column to automatically extend to fit a wrapped paragraph of text (without having to nest the other columns)? I'm trying to find a more elegant solution than adding artificial space in the adjacent columns since the text in the first column will be of variable length in different versions.
[image: screenshot of multirow table output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|cc|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{4cm}{This is a long paragraph of important information that should not spill over into the cell below, but as you can see, it is indeed spilling.} 
                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{xxx}} & xxx \\ \cline{3-3} 
                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                     & xxx \\ \cline{2-3} 
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{xxx}                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually outside of the limits of what is reasonable for `multirow`. As the other answer shows sometimes you can solve it, but it requires some guessing and in more complicated situations that will become too hard.

A better solution is to use the `tabularray` package; it is designed for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{|p{4cm}|c|c|}
\hline
\SetCell[r=3]{l}{This is a long paragraph of important information that should not spill over into the cell below, but as you can see, it is indeed spilling.} 
                        & \SetCell[r=2]{c}{xxx} & xxx \\ \cline{3-3} 
                        &                       & xxx \\ \cline{2-3} 
                        & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{xxx} &                       \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. That does seem to work better for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Vertically expand the cells using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<factor>}`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[htp!]
    \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.3} % added <<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|cc|}
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{4cm}{This is a long paragraph of important information that should not spill over into the cell below, but as you can see, it is indeed spilling.} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{xxx}} & xxx \\ \cline{3-3} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                     & xxx \\ \cline{2-3} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{xxx}                        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```